# How does archive.is work?

Tags: facebook, security, proxy

I'm able to upload facebook profile pages through archive.is. Which means facebook doesn't think that it was a proxy / bot and doesn't even ask for a captcha. It even shows some man being logged in (!!!) on the shots of pages. As your can check yourself, this profile is named Nathan, and it's the same profile for all shots.

When I'm trying to archive ip-check site, it shows my own IP saying that I'm under the Netherlands proxy.

First, how does it work?

Second, how come this user Nathan isn't banned from Facebook for the "suspicious activity" because he visits thousands of randomly looking pages a day, is automated, and detected as being under the proxy by ip-checking sites, and he isn't even asked to complete a captcha, not a single time? How do I do the same?